# Intrinsic Locks and Synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am currently reading about [Intrinsic Locks and Synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) on oracle.com where I came to this particular example:

> Synchronized statements are also useful for improving concurrency with fine-grained synchronization. Suppose, for example, class MsLunch has two instance fields, `c1` and `c2`, that are never used together. All updates of these fields must be synchronized, but there's no reason to prevent an update of `c1` from being interleaved with an update of `c2` — and doing so reduces concurrency by creating unnecessary blocking. Instead of using synchronized methods or otherwise using the lock associated with this, we create two objects solely to provide locks.

```
public class MsLunch {
    private long c1 = 0;
    private long c2 = 0;
    private Object lock1 = new Object();
    private Object lock2 = new Object();

    public void inc1() {
        synchronized(lock1) {
            c1++;
        }
    }

    public void inc2() {
        synchronized(lock2) {
            c2++;
        }
    }
}
```

Before this section, `synchronized` methods where explained:

```
public synchronized void increment() {
    this.c++;
}
```

Which should be, and please correct me if I'm wrong, the same as

```
public void increment() {
    synchronized(this) {
        c++;
    }
}
```

if I do not add functionality to `increment()`, is that correct?

My question now comes from the phrase:

> but there's no reason to prevent an update of `c1` from being *interleaved* with an update of `c2`

I am not sure if I fully understand what "*interleaved*" means in this context. Does it mean, that if I e.g. remove `lock2` from the `MsLunch` example:

```
public class MsLunch {
    private long c1 = 0;
    private long c2 = 0;
    private Object lock1 = new Object();
    // private Object lock2 = new Object(); // 'lock2' is no more!

    public void inc1() {
        synchronized(lock1) {
            c1++;
        }
    }

    public void inc2() {
        synchronized(lock1) { // Using 'lock1' here too
            c2++;
        }
    }
}
```

I could get in trouble with locking? Say `thread-1` runs into `inc1()`, gets the lock from `lock1` but gets suspended before being able to increment or release the lock. Now `thread-2` is entering `inc2()` where another lock is created for `lock1`. Is this what is being avoided by using another `lock2` and is this the reason why I would not use simply `this` as lock-provider? Or in other words: Can this cause a problem?

Comment: No, you can't get in *trouble*, you'll just unnecessarily prevent `c1` and `c2` from being increased at the same time, since they share the same lock (whether it's `this` or a separate `lock1`) and have therefore a dependency between them through the lock.

Comment: @Kayaman Oh, the German translation of "interleaved" is something like "into each other" or "into one another" so I got a bit confused. But why does this prevent `c1` and `c2` at the same time? In the `lock1`-only example, if `lock1` holds a lock "*anywhere*" in the code, does that mean it will block elsewhere too? So `thread-2` has to wait for `thread-1` to update `c1` before it can update `c2`. This also implies that each object can only provide *one* lock at the same time - that just wasn't that clear to me from reading the chapter.

Comment: Yes, each object provides one lock at a time. That's the whole idea why synchronized works like it does.

Comment: @Kayaman Alright, I had a bit of a wrong preconception but now I get it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two locks here just to have possibility to increase `c1` and`c2` independently and not wait when the lock is released. So if `Thread-1` enters to sync block in`c1` and acquires a `lock1`, another `Thread-2` will able increase `c2` without waiting when `thread-1` releases a lock.

---

**Important to note:**

Using of `this` as share monitor has an own issue because a reference on the instance of `MsLunch` is visible outside of `MsLunch`. For example. `Thread-3` able to acquire a lock for: `synchronized (msLunchInstance)` outside of this class.

Comment: Thanks! +1 for the explanation regarding `this`. I didn't think about this implication - using `this` could really hide some performance issues in a *very* gross way if I get this right! :D